# daml: <disabledText/> in ToolTip

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

I have found several examples for how to define tooltips in a config.daml file. There is sometimes an element `<disabledText />` inside of the tooltip.

Does anybody know what this elemnt is good for?

Example:

```xml
<tool id="appmodule_linktool" caption="Link to data" loadOnClick="true" className="LinkTool" largeImage="Images\AddInDesktop32.png" keytip="ST" smallImage="AddInDesktop16.png">
  <tooltip heading="Link Tool">Follows a link to the corresponding web page.<disabledText /></tooltip>
</tool>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this wiki topic](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-Framework)

Quote:

> Command ToolTips also support a disabledText element; this string
>   becomes the ToolTip whenever the command is disabled.

In short, if you have logic that enable/disables your button, this text will be displayed when the button is disabled. For example, you write a button that makes use of the network analyst extension. However someone does not have this extension, you could check for that, *disable* your button and provide text to say "this button is disabled because you do not have network analyst"